# Reading / writing file on local machine

Tags: firefox-addon

I pretty much copied this code right out of the [MDN File I/O](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Reading_from_a_file) page.. except I added an if statement to check if the file exists already and if it does, read it instead.

```
        Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
               getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).
               get("Desk", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
    file.append("test.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        this.user_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*10001) +'-'+ Math.floor(Math.random()*10001) +'-'+ Math.floor(Math.random()*10001) +'-'+ Math.floor(Math.random()*10001);

        var ostream = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file)
        var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].
                        createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
        converter.charset = "UTF-8";
        var istream = converter.convertToInputStream(this.user_id);

        // The last argument (the callback) is optional.
        NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(status) {
            if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
                alert('Error '+ status);
                return;
            }

            alert('File created');  
        });
    } else
    {
        NetUtil.asyncFetch(file, function(inputStream, status) {
            if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
                alert('error '+ status);
                return;
            }

            // The file data is contained within inputStream.
            // You can read it into a string with
            this.user_id = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, inputStream.available());
        });
        alert('File exists already, do not create');    
    }

    alert(this.user_id);
```

It creates the file just fine, I can open it and read it. If the file already exists however, it does not populate `this.user_id`.. just equals null. So my issue is specifically with reading the file.

Comment: Did you check if the file has the correct contents?

Comment: @David - not sure if I know what you mean, you referring to `contentType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File reading in your code works asynchronously - meaning that your code completes (including the `alert()` call which will show that `this.user_id` is `null`), *then* at some point the callback from `NetUtil.asyncFetch()` gets called with the data. Until that happens `this.user_id` won't be set of course. If you move `alert(this.user_id)` into the callback function it should show the correct value.

Note that it is highly recommended to keep file I/O operations asynchronous because they might take significant time depending on the current state of the file system. But you have to structure your code in such a way that it doesn't assume that file operations happen immediately.

Comment: Thank you again Wladimir (I feel like I should be paying you). This makes a lot of sense I have made a few changes and I am happy with the result. Thanks.